# Why did TOOL's Adam Jones not return to film?

Tags: tool

The release of Jurassic World made me wonder if Adam Jones would play a role in sculpture and makeup within the film

Within the past he's done work on Jurassic Park, Predator 2, Ghostbusters 2, and Nightmare on Elm Street. But, since this time frame, he has not returned to film. Considering he had a solid foot-in-the-door, scholarships, and a huge reputation at the time, you'd think he would of (at the very least,) done film on the side.

Granted, I am certainly glad that Adam Jones has dedicated much of his artistic abilities towards TOOL, but I've always wondered why he left his film career in the past.

Comment: Leaving this as a comment since it can't all be substantiated: my best guess is because he knew the court case was wrapping up and Tool would soon be back in the studio (that case was wrapped up in March I believe).  Or maybe he lost interest in movies.  I know he's worked on the X-Files comic book in recent years, and 2 years ago he got married and had a child.  Those could be factors as well.